# Tab bar navigation without component screen render

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way to press on tab bar and not render component screen? i have been passing null function but it still renders blank screen. i want that wherever you press it stays on home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid navigation to the screen by creating your custom `tabBar` component in which you can handle `onPress` to each `tabBarComponent` so you can avoid navigation and do some action instead. Take a closer look at the example from react-navigation documentation here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar

This line of code from the example should be helpful for you:

```
        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
            canPreventDefault: true,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a listener to the Screen.

```
          component={() => null}
          listeners={() => ({
            tabPress: (e) => {
              e.preventDefault(); // Prevents navigation
              // Your code here for when you press the tab
            },
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create empty component

```
export function EmptyComponent() {
 return null;
 }
```

step 2: render empty component in your bottomTabNav

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="EmptyComponent" //Render Empty Component
    component={EmptyComponent}
    options={{}}
    listeners={({navigation}) => ({
      tabPress: event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        navigation.navigate('UploadPosts'); // Navigate to different Stack Navigator, which is created by createStackNavigator
      },
    })}
  />
```